# C++: set value to floating point variable by bits

Tags: c++, floating-point, bit-manipulation

I have a large message which must be initialized to default values. The message is a structure with many sub-structures, enums, etc. I have an automatically generated description file of the message, which contains the field-by-field parse of the message: field start byte, start bit, length, type, default value.
I've implemented a mechanism which treats the message as a bits buffer and initializes it according to the description file. But.... I have a problem with floating point defaults.
How do I make the automation of setting floating point variable bitwise?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends, what should the default value of the floating point members be? If it's zero, then all zero are just fine.

Comment: But then, if you're programming in C++, why can't you have a default constructor for each structure that initializes all its own members in the proper way? Non-virtual members functions (like constructors) doesn't "pollute" the data of a structure.

Comment: The default values can defer, they aren't known ahead. The description file is given to me by a third party.

Comment: I see your answer down there, but.... I'm curious as to what your `MSG_STRUCT_TYPE` looks like. In particular, I'm curious as to why you have to define an `int startByte = 28;` as an index into your `msgBuf`. With properly defined structures, you shouldn't have to manually specify an index like that just to get to a particular spot in your `OutputMsg`, you should just be able to refer to the `offsetof()` a particular member and the compiler will figure out what that offset is. Then if your structure changes, the offset changes automatically. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof

Comment: The startByte definition was only for the short analogy example here. As I've mentioned in my original post, I've a file, which contains the definition of the struct - start bytes, bits, lengths and types for all struct's fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've managed to solve it by myself.
Assume the following:

```
MSG_STRUCT_TYPE OutputMsg; // e.g.750 bytes
int startByte = 28; // the start byte of floating point field in the message
float defVal = -1.75f; // the default value for the field above
```

Now, using the *reinterpret_cast* we can do the following manipulation:

```
unsigned char* bytes_to_set = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&defVal);
unsigned char* msgBuff = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&OutputMsg);
*reinterpret_cast<float*>(&msgBuf[startByte]) = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(bytes_to_set);
```

That do the job.

---

After implementing and checking  **njuffa**'s comment bellow, I'm adding it as another (simplier and cleaner) answer:

```
unsigned char* msgBuff = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&OutputMsg);
memcpy(&msgBuf[startByte], &defVal, sizeof(float);
```

Comment: With modern optimizing compilers, a simple `memcpy()` is often the clearest, non-convoluted, and efficient way to affect such data transfers between differently typed data. I would suggest giving that a try.

Comment: Sometimes, our minds neglects the simple ways and search for complex paths...)) I'll definitely try it when in back to work. Thanks.